# How to select only rows from a table one clumns value is more than b table count value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Table A:

```
id, name, school_code
-------------------
1,David,10601
2,Jack,10602
3,John,10603
4,Hank,10602
5,Daisy,10601
6,Kelly,10602
7,May,10602
8,Mayme,10602
```

Table B:

```
id, school_code,max_stu
------------------------
1,10601,10
2,10602,5
3,10603,6
```

How select table B rows value of max_stu more than table A count(*) where a.school_code=b.school_code ?

Expected result:

```
id, school_code,max_stu
------------------------
1,10601,10
3,10603,6
```

Comment: The title says "less", the question says "more". Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would use a correlated subquery. That looks pretty similar to how you already formulated it.

```
SELECT *
       FROM `table b` `b`
       WHERE `b`.`max_stu` > (SELECT count(*)
                                     FROM `table a` `a`
                                     WHERE `a`.`school_code` = `b`.`school_code`);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<` be `>`?

Comment: @forpas: Hmm, they wrote "max_stu less than table A count(*) ..." which makes be believe `<` is the right operator. Am I missing something there?

Comment: True, but the expected result, say for `1,10601,10` indicates the opposite.

Comment: @forpas: Now they changed the question, it should be indeed `>`.